# iOS storyboards segue push not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard

I am having a minor problem with segue using push in Xcode's storyboards. Its pretty straightforward: even with the simplest case, I can't manage to get it working.

The setup: http://d.pr/i/ahCG

Which is basically just a 1-view project, added another view controller, embedded that into a navigation controller and made the segue and setting the mode to "push". There is absolutely nothing happening when I push the test button. If I make the segue with modal however, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to embed the source view (not the destination view) into a nav controller to do a push segue.

Comment: Any idea why this still wouldn't work even when the source view IS embedded in a nav controller? Using Xcode 5, iOS7.

Comment: Not immediately, but that sounds like a good subject for a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the mode to "modal" instead of "push".

Comment: Why is using modal instead of push the wrong thing to do?

Comment: This is not wrong. Just different approach. If you use "push" you need write code for navigate but if you use "modal" this happen automatically.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392744/what-is-the-difference-between-modal-and-push-segue-in-storyboards

Comment: If you need some logic between switching views use "push" if not use "modal"